# Android Wear - start wear activity from handheld action

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm sending a notification from an android handheld device to an android wear device.  I'd like to include an action with the notification that starts an activity on the android wear device.

How do I set the pending intent to an activity on the wear device?  I'm able to launch the activity if the notification is created on the wearable, but not if the notification is created on the phone and then sent to the wearable.

```
 // creating action for push notification created on handheld
 public NotificationCompat.Action CreateWearAppAction(Integer metricId) {
    // I wasnt able to look up the wear's main activity class since this is in the handheld project.
    Intent wearPageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri wearUri = Uri.parse("mywearapp://Test?MetricId=" + metricId);
    wearPageIntent.setData(wearUri);
    PendingIntent wearPagePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, wearPageIntent, 0);

    return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action_metric,
            "Open Charts on Wear", wearPagePendingIntent)
            .build();
}
```

Activity manifest from wear app that I'm trying to launch:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- deep link -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mywearapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you add some code? Wear service, wear manifest and mobile call would be needed.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the DataLayer sample included in the Android SDK Manager for API 20. It contains an example of how to start up an activity on the wearable after a user presses a button on the mobile device.

Comment: Just to give some details, basically this is about sending a Message via Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage from the handheld to the wearable.

Answer (score 0):

that **probably** is done with a bit of hackery.

create your own action and make the Wear.activity `<intent-filter` to use it. Something like:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myCompany.myApp.ACTION.openWearActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
```

then on your notification intent, created from the phone, you know it, just use that one:

```
new Intent("com.myCompany.myApp.ACTION.openWearActivity");
```

and voila !

Comment: I tried this out but I'm still not getting the wearable activity to boot up.

Comment: You probably need to add
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: Also tried this out w/ adding category and still doesn't start my wear Activity.