# can't start wearable app by handled devices

Tags: android, wear-os, start-activity

I'm working on a wear App.

I can start the App by handle device only if the same App has been started on the watch at least once since turning on the watch.

If I turn on the watch and try to start App by handled devices, App does not start.

If I click on App icon manually the App starts. Every time after this, the App starts correctly by handle devices.

How can I start App the first time without clicking on the icon?

In my handled Manifest file I have:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

In my wearable Manifestfile I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and

```
 <action android:name="com.exaple.sere.path5.ACTION.openWearActivity" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that Google Play Services, Google Search, and Android Wear are up to date. Have a look for them in the Updates list and update them, or just tap Update all at the top. You could also try [resetting your watch](http://www.digitaltrends.com/wearables/android-wear-problems/#ixzz4NmwqGcQ8 ) to factory settings via Settings > Reset device on the watch. Here are some related threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167859/android-wear-start-wear-activity-from-handheld-action and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004530/android-wear-app-not-installing-through-handset

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I followed it, but nothing is changed. My werable app does not start if watch is just turned on. If I want start it, the first time, I must click on the icon.